# How to grab TRTTIParamter's default value

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe, rtti

I have this class:

```
TMyClass = class
public
  function DoSomethingNice(const Value: string = 'Yes please!'): Boolean;
end;
```

Now, using RTTI, is it possible to get default value of parameter **Value** of method **DoSomethingNice**? if so, how?

I'm mostly interested in a D2010 solution, but XE will do also.

Comment: for now is not possible, but you can vote in this [QC 93943](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=93943)

Comment: @RRUZ thank you, I wasn't sure about this, but was expecting it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it is impossible, because RTTI has not information about default parameters.
default parameter values are used only at compile time

so, if we have...
`procedure test(x : integer = 3)`
and then call method without parameter value:
`test()` then it will be compiled as `test(3)`

to check this you can open CPU window in debugger:
and `test()` looks like

```
 mov  eax, $00000003
 call test
```